# What is a better way to apply arbitrary operations across an array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script that I use to graph time-domain data, including a method to create a new data channel based on raw data by specifying a formula.

For example, I have raw data collated in a [m x n] numpy array of floats as follows

```
x0   y00   y10   ...    yn0
x1   y01   y11   ...    yn1
:    :     :     :      :
xm   y0m   y1m   ...    ynm
```

The first column is the time data, subsequent columns represent various series. The series that are plotted are determined by matching string headers, for example:

```
headers = ["Time","Power","Frequency","Current","Voltage",...,"Series N"]
```

I then specify a formula as a string in the following format:

```
formula_str = "{Power}*{Frequency} + 3*{Current} + (3 if {Voltage}>0 else 0)"
```

Note that I use {} as an arbitrary identifier for a series name.

To turn this formula into a new data channel, my current solution is to iterate over the time-domain and manually generate data-points using `eval`.

```
# convert formula string to array references
for n,chan in enumerate(data_channels):
    # process reference to data channel
    formula_str = formula_str.replace("{%s}" % chan, "data[%d][x]" % n)

# generate channel data
formula_channel_data = []
for n in range(len(time_data)):
    formula_str_n = formula_str
    for m in range(len(data_channels)):
        formula_str_n = formula_str_n.replace("data[%d][x]" % m,str(data[m][n]))
    formula_channel_data += [eval(formula_str_n)]
formula_channel_data = np.array(chan_data)
```

The end result is I now have an additional data channel `z` of generated data.

```
x0   y00   y10   ...    yn0   zn0
x1   y01   y11   ...    yn1   zn1
:    :     :     :      :     :
xm   y0m   y1m   ...    ynm   znm
```

As you might expect, this is quite slow and I'm sure there must be a better (faster and more pythonic) way of implementing this. Is there another way this could be implemented that would improve on the above?

Comment: Why are you using this string-based solution in the first place?

Comment: Well for starters eval is slow.

Comment: There are two big issues.  1) turning the string input into working code. 2) making code that works well with your arrays. Iterating over the dimension will be slow.

Comment: @AMC - I select the different series to plot by referring to a string header, e.g. "Frequency". I don't know beforehand which column in my data array will represent the relevant series.

Comment: @acameron7 Can you tell us a bit more about the data? Some more context in general would be nice. If your columns have names etc. then using a single NumPy array might not the best choice for this.

Comment: @AMC see my edits. Hopefully that makes more sense now, the headers are stored separately as a list of strings and the data array contains the corresponding float data in the respective columns.

Comment: Do you need `numpy` at all?  With this sort of iteration nested lists should be just as easy, and faster.

Comment: @acameron7 Hmm if I were you I would just slap the whole thing into a Pandas DataFrame. No more worrying about where the columns are, and you can easily perform vectorized operations.

Comment: @hpaulj No particular reason I have to use numpy, could give basic lists a go

Comment: @AMC A Pandas DataFrame seems to match my data's structure a lot better, I'll probably switch to that. Doesn't completely replace the manual iteration though as it only appears to allow for basic binary operations, not things like conditional logic.

Comment: @acameron7 I don’t know how complex the conditional logic you’re thinking of is, but I know that something like the example in your post should be trivial.

Comment: @AMC You're right, using </> etc can probably accomplish the same thing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @acameron7 Yup! Good luck :)

Comment: For the sake of it, if you were sticking to this design then using a dictionary of NumPy would probably be a decent improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of your code, you're basically trying to build a mathematical function incrementally. Instead of using repeated string replacements, I would rewrite the general function as a Python function which takes in array references as arguments.

In Python, functions are first-class objects which can be stored in variables. Futhermore, there's [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) which allows you to take a function variable and spit out another function with specific arguments attached, such as specific arrays. The example given in the docs is very self-explanatory, and should generalize to for loops as you are using.